# post a <FORM> to sharepoint page

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I am doing following in one of my webpart .ascx file.

```
<FORM action="https://illustration.sagicorlifeusa.com/fse5/main/FormPost.aspx" id="frmLogin" method="post" target=blank>
    <TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%" border=0>
    <%= CompleteRequest %>
<input type="submit" name="__exclude__Submit" value="Run Sagicor Life Illustration Software Online" />
```

Notice the method="post"; However, looks like when I add this web-part, The hosting page already has a `<FORM/>` . How can I do the above POST?

Comment: What does `CompleteRequest` return? a string containing form fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`post`ing to a new window from inside an ASPX web form (which SharePoint is) is tricky, because the framework wraps everything in a `<form>` it keeps track of.  If you are required to post to the target page (i.e. `get` isn't good enough), you might have to:

1. create a separate .aspx page entirely to produce the form
2. open that form from within your Web Part with a JS call to `window.open` or an `<a href="..." target="blank"`
3. auto-post that form, with JavaScript, as soon as it loads.

(I have no firsthand experience with sharepoint; take this answer with a grain of salt.)